# zsh: how to get file expansion working in print statement

Tags: zsh, filenames

I have the following code which prints recursively all files inside /usr/local/include:

```
% files=(/usr/local/include/**/*(^/))
% print -l $files
```

Is it possible to get rid of the temporary variable? I would like to simply retrive a list of all files matched with the pattern.

I tried:

```
% print -l "(/usr/local/include/**/*(^/))"
```

with no success.

Comment: Try removing the `"(` and `)"`

Comment: Yes, it works. Really I didn't expect that it should be so simply. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print -rl /usr/local/include/**/*(^/)
```